# MVC Javascript Set Text Input Value Based on Model

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, model

I have an Html.DropDownListFor, a textbox, and a model that contains a list "sourceWatchListParameters".

My end goal is, when an item is selected in the dropdownlist, populate the textbox with a property "DefaultParameter" for that particular sourceWatchList.

```
$(function() {
    $('select#WatchListDropDown').change(function () {
        var e = document.getElementById("#WatchListDropDown").selectedIndex.value;

        @foreach (var watchlist in Model.sourceWatchListParameters)
        {
            @:if (watchlist.WatchListId == e)
            {
                @: var def = document.getElementById("expDefault");
                @: def.value = watchlist.DefaultParameter;
            }
        }

    })
});
```

The function is called correctly, but I can't figure out the logic/syntax to locate the right sourceWatchListParameter and display its DefaultParameter.  As it is now, I see no change in the textbox on selection.  I'm sure there's a simpler way to rewrite this.

Thanks for any guidance

Comment: What is `watchlist` and why you're mixing JS and jQuery?

Comment: I'm mixing them i suppose because I'm confused

Comment: Okay, and what is "DefaultParameter"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it finally as such :

```
$('select#WatchListDropDown').change(function () {
        @foreach (var w in Model.sourceWatchListParameters)
        {
            @:if ($('#WatchListDropDown').val() == "@w.WatchListId.ToString()")
            @:{
                @: $("#expDefault").val("@w.Description");
            @:}
        }
    })
```

Comment: with this solution you have in your javascript code all items written and all 'if' for each item

Comment: I'm sorry what do you mean?

Comment: I'm respond you in my answerd.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you have something like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
     m => m.WatchListDropDown, 
     Model.SourceListWatchListDropDown() ...)
```

Here you only have the value ('id') and the description, but you can do something like this to have the 3 values​​:

```
<select id="WatchListDropDown" name="WatchListDropDown">
@foreach (var wp in Model.sourceWatchListParameters)
{
   <option value="@wp.WatchListId" data-defparam="@wp.DefaultParameter">@wp.Description</option>
}
</select>
```

in this case, if you need get the default parameter, you only need to do this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#WatchListDropDown').bind('change', function () {
        var newValue = $(this).find('option:selected').data('defparam');
        $('#expDefault').val(newValue);;
    })
});
```

if your to render the page already have a value assigned, you can do the following:

```
   $('#WatchListDropDown').bind('change', function () {
       ...
   }).trigger('change');
```

**Edit**
Result for the solution of @Jonesy

Supposing that "Model.sourceWatchListParameters" has this value:

```
[
 {
    WatchListId = 1,
    Description = "Description 1"
 },
 {
    WatchListId = 3,
    Description = "Description 3"
 },
 {
    WatchListId = 3,
    Description = "Description 3"
 }
]
```

Your code would look like:

```
$('select#WatchListDropDown').change(function () {

    if ($('#WatchListDropDown').val() == "1")
        $("#expDefault").val("Description 1");
    }

    if ($('#WatchListDropDown').val() == "2")
        $("#expDefault").val("Description 2");
    }

    if ($('#WatchListDropDown').val() == "3")
        $("#expDefault").val("Description 3");
    }
})
```